# not able to write a big size data with UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE

Tags: xml, oracle, file-io

I created a xml which includes a big amount of data. Now I am trying to write that generated xml  into a file.

Declaration:

```
prodFeed_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
prodFeed_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('CSV_DIR', 'feed.xml', 'w', 32767);
```

WRITING INTO FILE:

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(prodFeed_file,l_xmltype.getClobVal);

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(prodFeed_file);
```

If `l_xmltype.getClobVal` returns limited record then it is working file but if the `l_xmltype.getClobVal` exceeds the size(almost 35 KB) it is giving an error:

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [UTL_FILE documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70943):

> "The maximum size of the buffer parameter is 32767 bytes unless you specify a smaller size in FOPEN. "

You will have to write the CLOB chunk by chunk. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_clob CLOB;
  v_clob_length INTEGER;
  pos INTEGER := 1;
  buffer VARCHAR2(32767);
  amount BINARY_INTEGER := 32760;
  prodFeed_file utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
  prodFeed_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('CSV_DIR', 'productFeedLargo.xml', 'w', 32767);
  v_clob := l_xmltype.getClobVal;
  v_clob_length := length(v_clob);

  WHILE pos < v_clob_length LOOP
    dbms_lob.read(v_clob, amount, pos, buffer);
    utl_file.put(prodFeed_file , char_buffer);
    utl_file.fflush(prodFeed_file);
    pos := pos + amount;
  END LOOP;

  utl_file.fclose(prodFeed_file);

END;
/
```

Comment: I posted an answer which just linked to the doc.  But as you've posted a workaround I've deleted my answer and added the link to yours.

Comment: Hi, would you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279365/utl-file-write-error-when-calling-utl-file-put-in-a-loop?