# How to write a large xml data field into a csv file

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am writing data from a table into csv file. Among other fields, clob column is there which has XML data. I am using util_file functionality to write it to csv file and no issues. But when it comes to clob column which holds XML data of size more than 50000 bytes, I am facing issue.
1. It throws error " ORA-29285: file write error "
2. To overcome the above error, through loop I was trying to write the data as chunk bu closing the file and re oppen in append mode. But it starts in a new line and it makes to lose the csv functionality.

Can any one please let me know, how to write the large xml data into one column ( one cell ) in csv file.

Comment: You don't need to close and reopen file. The problem is here `UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file_handler,xmltype.getClobVal);`. 
And solution is here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652569/not-able-to-write-a-big-size-data-with-utl-file-put-line)

Comment: In that solution, they are writing to a .xml file. But my requirement is to write it as .csv file.